# How to upload an object to AWS S3 with "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using the awssdk for c++ to upload data to an S3 bucket. I am using the method `PutObject()` of the class `Aws::S3::S3Client` to upload the data.

However, before uploading the data, I need to know the content-length of the data I am uploading. I need to either set the content-length in the request (the request is of type `Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectRequest`). Or the awssdk library will try to determine the size of the body by itself (the awssdk does that by seeking to the end of payload data to read its size).

Either way, in my case I don't know yet the content-length of the data I am uploading. I am working on a server that compresses data. I have to wait for the compression to end to know the final size of the compressed data. I don't want to wait for that. Instead, I want to start uploading to S3 as the compressed data is being produced. The way that can be done is to use "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" when sending the HTTP post request to the S3 server.

**Is there a way to use `Aws::S3::S3Client` to upload the data with "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" ? ***

I've downloaded the source of the awssdk for c++, I've tweaked it a bit to force send "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" in the http request. But the S3 server returned HTTP error code 501 NotImplemented:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>NotImplemented</Code>
    <Message>A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented</Message>
    <Header>Transfer-Encoding</Header>
    <RequestId>8F55B09D484DD66C</RequestId>
    <HostId>gZk6zaPcObsTfclz0zXvKGtPT5udzDKigIrm7laD3csG30vhx3pa0eFFS8nh6t9k7XkDeJRm9Z4=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: You need to look at multi-part uploads. I haven't used the C++ SDK, so can't give you more information.

Comment: Looks like [chunked also needs the final content-length to be known](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=561616#jive-message-543097) so yes, only buffering + multipart would work in this case